# Linking an html page to another one

Tags: html, hyperlink, frontend, href

I have an index.html page (homepage), where the word "login" is supposed to be linked to the login page (login.html). However, when I click "login", it shows the "file not found" message. I can't figure out why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
            <p><a href="‪‪‪file:///C:/Users/Beatriz/Desktop/project/login.html" id="login">Login</a>
            <a href="" id="signup"> Sign Up </a></p>
            <br/>
            <h1 align="center"> Prototype Name </h1>
            <h2 align="center"> Prototype Slogan </h2>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <table id="menu">
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="" id="mainlink"> Home </a></td>
                    <td ><a href="" id="mainlink"> About Us </a></td>
                    <td><a href="" id="mainlink"> Support </a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: Somehow it started working after I erased the href and wrote exactly the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

Change href to if they are in the same folder.

```
<p><a href="‪‪‪login.html" id="login">Login</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't totally understand your answer
"Change href to...?"

Comment: Instead of using absolute path, use relative path. To do that,  just use file name alone. Sorry for not explaining fully. Absolute path is a full filename as in "c:\example\example\login.html" while a relative path is simply a path relative to the active file such as "login.html"

Comment: Oh, I see now, thank you. I've tried it too... It's really weird.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't

Comment: It should unless, the file literally doesn't exist in the directory. Check also case, some systems are case sensitive

Comment: Everything was in the file. It started working after I erased it and wrote it again somehow... Thank you anyway!